# no repeating values in array

Tags: c

I need to make a program that stores numbers inside of an array. But it  must have no duplicate elements.

```
  int x;
  int z[8];

  for( x = 0; x<8;x++) 
      printf("number: ");
      scanf("%d",&z[x]);
  }

  for( x=0;x<8;x++) {
    printf("%d ",z[x]); 
  }
```

Comment: Whenever it should take a new number, loop through the array to see if that value is already there, and if it is, don't add the new number. There's not much else to say if you're not going to show us some code (you can edit your question and insert some code).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As for your problem, you might want to do some research about [*sets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)).

Comment: @Blaze I already posted my code so far...

Comment: `do { /* read a number into a temporary variable (tmp) */ } while (isunique(tmp, user_nums, x) && (1 <= tmp) && (tmp <= 42)); user_nums[x] = tmp;` ... writing the function `isunique()` is left as an exercise :)

Answer (score 0):

First, initialize the array, so that  you do not end up reading an uninitialized value and fail the test.

```
int user_nums[6] = {0};
```

Next, you need to have another check in the `for` loop, to read the number again if it is a duplicate.

The code will look like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int x,y;
    int exists = 0;
    int user_nums[6] = {0};
    for( x = 0; x<6;x++){//for loop  to get the players selected numbers    

        do {
            exists = 0;
            printf("Enter a number(from the #'s 1-42): ");
            scanf("%d",&user_nums[x]);

            for(y =0; y < x; y++) { //to check for duplicates
                if (user_nums[x] == user_nums[y])
                {   
                    printf("Number already exists\n ");
                    exists = 1;             
                    break;
                }
            }

        }while (user_nums[x]<1 || user_nums[x]>42 || exists);//accepts only numbers from 1-42 which are not duplicates (continous to ask you for a number until condition is met).
    }

    printf("Your numbers: \n");

    for( x=0;x<6;x++){
        printf("%d ",user_nums[x]); // prints the numbers you inputed.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if the size of `user_num` is `10000`?

Comment: @DavideSpataro: I try to answer only what is asked. Since the OP did not ask for any sort of efficiency or about handling huge no of inputs, I did not address those. I made minimal changes to his program so that he can easily relate to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following `code` could work in O(n):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int user_nums[6];
    int index[50];

    for (int i = 0; i != sizeof(index) / sizeof(index[0]); ++i)
        index[i] = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(user_nums) / sizeof(user_nums[0]); ++i) {
        for (;;) {
            printf("Enter a number(from the #'s 1-42): ");
            scanf("%d", user_nums + i);
            if (user_nums[i] < 1 || user_nums[i] > 42) {
                printf("wrong number\n");
                continue;
            }
            if (index[user_nums[i]] != -1) {
                printf("dump number\n");
                continue;
            }
            index[user_nums[i]] = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("Your numbers: \n");

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        printf("%d ", user_nums[i]);

    return 0;
}
```